# React share to social networks preview image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We have a SPA and have a problem with sharing to social networks, since it's crawler don't get pictures automatically, and we need to specify og:image. 
What is the way to produce images for all pages, considering user can take random url and past it to social network?

Comment: you can try pre build library for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **static website**, you can use static pre-renderer like [react-snapshot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-snapshot)

For **dynamic website** you have few options.

1. you can use any pre renderer library (middleware that you install on your server).
2. You have to use SSR technique. you can configure your own or can use [nextjs](https://nextjs.org/) or [razzle](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle)

Answer (score -1):

Install in react:
npm install react-share --save
refer Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-share